# How to split images up equally in html?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For my code I cannot seem to get the flex box to work to equally split the screen in order to have 2 images horizontal and 1 full image on the right side. The picture is an example of the layout I am targeting but flipped. Thank you.

[image]

CSS

```
   body{
    margin: 0px;
     }

    .parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }  

   .startup1{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 0px;
   }
    .startup2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 0px;
  }
    .startup3 {
    flex: 1;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 0px;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <img class="startup1" src="startup1.jpg" alt="Shop Image">
            <img class="startup2" src="startup2.jpg" alt="Shop Image">
            <img class="startup3" src="startup3.jpg" alt="Shop Image">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: your HTML markup is best suited for CSS `grid`, not `flex`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Hey I am working it out using CSS grid. I will update post soon.

Comment: grid-template-areas would be a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **CSS grid**, and slightly change your markup:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  height: 200px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b"
    "a c";
  gap: 0.5rem;
  
  &>div {
    position: relative;
    
    &.startup1 { grid-area: a; }
    &.startup2 { grid-area: b; }
    &.startup3 { grid-area: c; }
    
    & img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="startup1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" alt="Shop Image"></div>
  <div class="startup2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/200/300" alt="Shop Image"></div>
  <div class="startup3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/322/200/300" alt="Shop Image"></div>
</div>
```